# Detect 10-bit color support on display

Tags: c++, windows, colors, directx, monitor

I want to add support for 10-bit color in my DirectX C++ Windows app.
I'm talking about the 10-bit per RGB channel (30-bits total for RGB) using DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10A2_UNORM.

How to detect if the system supports that, I mean if the display monitor actually supports this mode?

Because for example, I'm enumerating display modes list:

```
  IDXGIOutput *output=null; for(Int i=0; OK(adapter->EnumOutputs(i, &output)); i++)
  {
     DXGI_FORMAT mode=DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10A2_UNORM;
     UInt descs_elms=0; output->GetDisplayModeList(mode, 0, &descs_elms, null); // get number of mode descs
     RELEASE(output);
  }
```

And even though my laptop display doesn't support 10-bit, I still get valid results, including the list of resolutions.
Later on I can create a full screen swap chain, having 10-bit, and all works OK.

However because I don't know if the monitor is 10-bit or 8-bit, then I don't know if I need to manually apply some dithering to simulate 10-bit.

So what I want to know, if the display is actually 10-bit = no dithering needed, or is it 8-bit = then I will apply my custom dithering shader.

I'm working with both classic Win32/WinAPI and the new Universal Windows Platform (so I need solution for both platforms).

Answer (score 3):

You are probably better off having some kind of user-setting to turn on/off dithering and just using `DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10A2_UNORM` for your swapchain.

Note that `DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10A2_UNORM` is also a valid HDR format, but requires manual application of the ST.2084 color-curve and setting the color-space appropriately to indicate the use of wide-gamut (i.e. HDR10). You could use `DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT` and render in linear color-space, but you are leaving it up to the system to do the 'correct' thing which may or may not match your expectations.

> For non-HDR/4kUHD scenarios, you can't really get anything more than 8-bit with windowed mode or UWP CoreWindows swapchains anyhow because DWM is converting you to 8-bit. 10-bit scan out for Win32 'classic' desktop apps is possible with exclusive full-screen mode but there are a lot of variables (DVI cables don't support it for example).

See [High Dynamic Range and Wide Color Gamut](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt742103.aspx), as well as the D3D12HDR sample [Win32](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Desktop/D3D12HDR)  / [UWP](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/tree/master/Samples/UWP/D3D12HDR)

Comment: Hi Chuck, thank you very much for your reply. This is what I'm currently doing. As of right now this is the best solution with having a user setting.
However it has some downfalls - it's an inconvenience to the user to have to set something, rather than having this autodetected, and another problem is that user simply may not know what his monitor supports, and if he chooses wrong, then he may actually get worse quality.
For example he may select 10-bit precision, thinking he will get better quality than 8-bit.

Comment: But in reality with the 10-bit setting, the dithering shader will get disabled, and if his monitor is 8-bit, then it will look worse without the dithering shader.
So in that user setting, I have to make it really clear, what this option does.
The best way, would be if DirectX provided an option to detect what is actually supported and what not. I'd like to request that new functionality to be added in the future.
BTW. this is my game engine, now several years in development http://www.esenthel.com/
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Figuring out whether monitor *really* supports 10-bit mode seems to be very tricky since a lot of of 10-bit models are actually 8-bit + dither (and a lot of 8-bit models are just 6-bit + dither). At least in some software I'm familiar with such check was implemented through white list of display models. So I think it would be better for you to always use `DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT` (this one is probably supported by most adapters) or `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT` as output format and let system convert it according to display expectations. Custom dithering can be left as option for user.